# Multiple Child Nodes in EnumerateChildNodesWithName

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, nodes, removechild

I'm removing and adding nodes using enumerateChildNodesWithName. I wondering if there is a way of using the enumerateChildNodesWithName with multiple names. For example, at the moment I am using the below:

```
    nodeBase.enumerateChildNodesWithName("ground", usingBlock: {
        node, stop in
        if node.position.x + positionX < -self.frame.size.width/2 - sizeSegmentWidth/2 {
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
    })

    nodeBase.enumerateChildNodesWithName("obstacle", usingBlock: {
        node, stop in
        if node.position.x + positionX < -self.frame.size.width/2 - sizeSegmentWidth/2 {
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
    })
```

But what I'm hoping to do is something like this (this doesn't work, just an example of what I'm trying to do):

```
    nodeBase.enumerateChildNodesWithName("ground" || "obstacle", usingBlock: {
        node, stop in
        if node.position.x + positionX < -self.frame.size.width/2 - sizeSegmentWidth/2 {
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") { node, _ in
    if node.name == "ground" || node.name == "obstacle" {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`"*"` means you'll enumerate over all nodes that are children of the scene (assuming it's the scene calling `enumerateChildNodesWithName`). If you wanted to check **all** nodes you would instead use `"//*"`.

Comment: This is great, this will free up several lines of code. Thank you.